# EF Many to many causes duplicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have problem with many to many relationship because it causes a duplicates record.

I have those classes:

```
class Flyer { Id, virtual ICollection<FlyerPage> Pages }

class FlyerPage { Id, FlyerId, virtual Flyer Flyer, ICollection<FlyerPageKeyword> Keywords }
```

And

```
class FlyerPageKeyword { Id, Key, virtual ICollection<FlyerPage> Pages }
```

So `FlyerPage` and `FlyerPageKeyword` are many to many. It works and records are saved to DB.

But it adds also duplicates of keywords.

My context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("name=DbConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Flyer> Flyers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FlyersEntityConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FlyersPageEntityConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FlyersPageKeywordsEntityConfiguration());
    }
}



public class FlyersEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Flyer>
{
    public FlyersEntityConfiguration()
    {
        this.Map(flyer => flyer.ToTable("Flyer", "Flyers"));

        this.HasMany(flyer => flyer.Pages)
            .WithRequired(page => page.Flyer)
            .HasForeignKey(page => page.FlyerId);
    }
}

public class FlyersPageEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FlyerPage>
{
    public FlyersPageEntityConfiguration()
    {
        this.Map(pages => pages.ToTable("Page", "Flyers"));
        this.HasMany(page => page.Keywords).WithMany(keywords => keywords.FlyerPages).Map(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ToTable("PageKeywords", "Flyers.Page");
            cfg.MapLeftKey("FlyerPageId");
            cfg.MapRightKey("KeywordId");
        });
    }
}
public class FlyersPageKeywordsEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FlyerPageKeyword>
{
    public FlyersPageKeywordsEntityConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Keyword", "Flyers.Page");
    }
}
```

And `Flyer` is aggregate root so I operate on it. Can't save only keywords.

```
var context = new Context();
        var flyer = new Flyer
        {
            Pages = new List<FlyerPage>
            {
                new FlyerPage
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Keywords = new List<FlyerPageKeyword> {new FlyerPageKeyword {Key = "One"}}
                },
                new FlyerPage
                {
                    Keywords = new List<FlyerPageKeyword> {new FlyerPageKeyword {Key = "Two"}}
                }
            }
        };
        context.Flyers.Add(flyer);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is `FlyerPage` and `FlyerPages` the same (typo)?

Comment: Yes, it's spelling mistake.

Comment: Can you clarify what's the issue? The combination of `FlyerPageId, KeywordId` should be unique by your current design.

Comment: In table "Flyers.Page.Keyword" there are duplicates. Id Key
1 One
2 One
3 One
4 Two

Comment: Well, this is because nothing prevents that. Create unique index on `Key` column, handle correctly the `FlyerPageKeyword` entity creation and there you go.

Comment: "correctly the FlyerPageKeyword entity creation and there you go" what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Avoid duplicates, your flyer assignment should look like

```
var context = new Context();
        var flyer = new Flyer
        {
            Pages = new List<FlyerPage>
            {
                new FlyerPage
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Keywords = new List<FlyerPageKeyword>
                        {
                          context.Keywords.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "One") ?? new FlyerPageKeyword {Key = "One"}
                        }


                },
                new FlyerPage
                {
                    Keywords = new List<FlyerPageKeyword> 
                         {
                          context.Keywords.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Two")?? new FlyerPageKeyword {Key = "Two"}
                         }
                }
            }
        };
        context.Flyers.Add(flyer);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically its all about using existing keyword entries before creating new ones:

```
someKeyword = context.Keywords.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "One") ?? new FlyerPageKeyword {Key = "One"};
```

If you ever just `new` a keyword which already exists, you get your duplicates.